# Universal cover of pair of pants

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, covering-spaces

I am studying some algebraic topology. I am wondering, what is the universal cover of a pair of pants? I'm rather stuck on this problem. Also, is there a nice way to visualize the cover? Thanks.

Comment: One inch circle of cloth at every stitch, duh.

Comment: Do you know fundamental groups?  Also, how much hyperbolic geometry do you know? (hyperbolic geometry isn't necessary, but it is helpful)

Comment: I know about fundamental groups. I know the basics of hyperbolic geometry (I have studied it mostly in the context of Riemann surfaces).

Answer (score 0):

Hint: A pair of pants deformation retracts to a wedge of two circles or the figure eight space. The universal cover is the fiber product of the universal cover of the figure eight space and a pair of pants.

More visually, identify two loops that generate $\pi_1$ and cut across these loops to make the simply connected. Doing the same thing on $S^1 \wedge S^1$ gives you a pair of intersecting segments, and $F_2 = \pi_1(S^1 \wedge S^1)$ copies of these are glued appropriately to produce the universal cover. After cutting, the pair of pants should look like a "thickened" cross, and gluing these the same way would produce its universal cover.